# Selenium chromedriver or another webdriver on CHROMEBOOK

Tags: selenium-webdriver, path, chromebook

Hey anyone that knows how to install a chromedriver or another webdriver for chromebook?
Trying to go the usual way for selenium and trying to download the accurate version of chromedriver
for my system I receive a download folder with the usual `readMe.txt` and a file named chromedriver without any file extension witch doesn't work even do I put it so it's accessible for the `$PATH`. So what do I do?

---